# row-wise operation in tidyverse using entire data

Tags: r, apply

Say we have some data

```
w <- 1:3
x <- 5:7
y <- c(3, 2, 3)
z <- c(3, 2, 5)
df <- data.frame(w,x,y,z)
```

Then I wish to create a new vector which runs the following

```
apply(df, 1, function(data) sum(2^(seq_along(data)) * data))
```

How can I run this `apply` function in Tidyverse?

I'm finding issues relating to that the data is the input rather than a specific column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ditch the loop and the packages, and simply do

```
rowSums(2^col(df) * df)
# [1]  94  76 138
```

`col(df)` gives you a matrix where the column values are the column numbers.  So you can use that for your exponent, multiply by the original data, take the row sums, and avoid any loops or packages all together.